# Python, R return different results for left join

Tags: python, r, pandas, left-join, tidyverse

I'm working with some code for joining two files together and tried it out in both Python and R. I thought the code below would return the same result, but when I joined the datasets and then counted the NAs in a particular column the Python code had more NAs. Any thoughts on why?

**R CODE**:

```
subs %>% 
  select(-revenue) -> subs

subs %>% 
  left_join(rev, by = "name") -> fullsubs

missingvalues <- map(fullsubs, ~sum(is.na(.)))

still_missing <- missingvalues$revenue

fullsubs %>% 
  filter(!is.na(revenue)) -> full_filtered

not_missing <- nrow(full_filtered)

results <- c("Matches"=format(as.numeric(not_missing),big.mark=","), "Still Missing"=format(as.numeric(still_missing),big.mark=","))
print(results, big.mark = ",")
```

**Python code:**

```
fulldata = subs.merge(rev, on='name', how = 'left')

missing = fulldata.isnull().sum()

notmissing = fulldata.notnull().sum()

d = {'Matches': [notmissing["revenue_y"]], '"Still Missing': [missing["revenue_y"]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

**EDIT:**
The issues ended up being white space. After I trimmed the white space from the beginning and end of the column that I was joining on I was able to get the same result from R and Python. Does anyone have insight into why or how R and Python parse white space differently?

Updated code that provides the same result:

````
```{r  message=FALSE, warning = FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(scales)
library(reticulate)
```

## R CODE

```{r message=FALSE, warning = FALSE}
rev <- read_csv("company_revenues.csv")
subs <- read_csv("subscribers.csv")


subs$company_name <- str_trim(subs$company_name, c("both"))
rev$company_name <- str_trim(rev$company_name, c("both"))


subs %>% 
  select(-company_revenue) -> subs

subs %>% 
  left_join(rev, by = "company_name") -> fullsubs

missingvalues <- map(fullsubs, ~sum(is.na(.)))

still_missing <- missingvalues$company_revenue

fullsubs %>% 
  filter(!is.na(company_revenue)) -> full_filtered

not_missing <- nrow(full_filtered)

results <- c("Matches"=format(as.numeric(not_missing),big.mark=","), "Still Missing"=format(as.numeric(still_missing),big.mark=","))
print(results, big.mark = ",")
```



## PYTHON CODE 

```{python}
import pandas as pd

revp = pd.read_csv("company_revenues.csv", error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')
subsp = pd.read_csv("subscribers.csv", error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')


#change comapny name to the same type 
revp['company_name']=revp['company_name'].astype(str)
subsp['company_name']=subsp['company_name'].astype(str)


#strip white space before and after word
revp['company_name']=revp["company_name"].str.strip()
subsp['company_name']=subsp["company_name"].str.strip()

fulldata = subsp.merge(revp, on='company_name', how = 'left')

missing = fulldata.isnull().sum()
notmissing = fulldata.notnull().sum()

d = {'Matches': [notmissing["company_revenue_y"]], 'Still Missing': [missing["company_revenue_y"]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```
````

Comment: This may be difficult to debug if you can't provide a reproducible sample of your data. Part of the reason may be the key you're joining on, if you're reading from a flat file, may get mangled due to different file-parsing that could be used in both packages (`dplyr` and `pandas`).

Comment: I found a solution to the problem. It was white space. (Once stripped the results matched.) If anyone has insight on why the two programs treat white space differently that would be interesting. This shouldn't require a sample of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the `read_csv` functions. If you have a look at the *readr* package documentation: https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html, the function default is set to `trim_ws = TRUE`. This means that the leading and trailing whitespace are trimmed from the start. The *pandas* `read_csv` function does not have that functionality, and so you would need to run `str.strip` after reading in the data.